# Confidence interval problem 1

Tags: statistics

An economist tries to find the IQ (intelligence quotient) of kids in a big city. If the average IQ is 100 and the deviation is 15, the probabilities that a child has greater IQ than 125, less than 95 and between 90 and 110 are:

a. 0,0485 - 0,3707 - 0,4514.

b. 0,3707 - 0,4514 - 0,0485.

c. 0,0485 - 0,4514 - 0,3707.

d. 0,3707 - 0,0485 - 0,4514.

I got so far:

greater than 125:

P (X≥125) = 1- P(X≤125)

Z = X-μ/σ

Z = 125-100/15

Z = 1,67

P(X≤125) = 0,95254

P (X≥125) = 1- 0,95254

P (X≥125) = 0,04746

less than 95:

P (x≤95) = ?

Z = 95-100/15 = -0,33

P (x≤95) = 0,3707

between 90 and 110:

P (90≤X110) = P(X≤110) - [1- P(X≤90)]

P (90≤X110) = 0,74857 -(1-0,25143)

P (90≤X110) = 0

Am i doing it right? what would be the answer?

Comment: Here are somewhat more-precise answers from R than you can get by standardizing and (perhaps) rounding to use printed normal tables:  `mu = 100;  sg = 15; a = 1 - pnorm(125, mu, sg); a` returns 0.04779035, then `b = pnorm(95, mu, sg); b` returns 0.3694413, and
`c = diff(pnorm(c(90,110), mu, sg));  c` returns 0.4950149. // So in order to answer the question you have to achieve the same degree of imprecision as the authors! // Both formal Answers give helpful clues (+1 times 2)

Answer (score 1):

You are doing well! I could only find a small blunder. 
$P(90 \leq X \leq 110) = P(X \leq 110) - P(X \leq 90)$, instead of
the expression you used.

Comment: but when greater than 125 and between 90 and 100 i'm not finding the correct answer, why would that be? what would be the correct answer?

Comment: The normal table used by the answer sheet seems to be slightly incorrect. By calculating these probabilities in $R$, I obtain that the correct answers are: 0.047, 0.369 and 0.495. (The differences seem to occur because of rounding $Z$).

Answer (score 1):

The probability  = the area under the curve(Probability Density function)

[image]

Therefore,

$$ \Pr(a\le x \le b) = \Pr(x \le b) - \Pr(x \le a)$$